# Range attribute issue in data annotation

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on Web API where I have put the `[Range]` attribute on a nullable double field. Here is the expression:

```
[Range(0, 6,ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
public Nullable<double> int_term { get; set; }
```

But when I test it, it only accepts one digit ie. 1 or 2 up to 6, etc.. If I put 12, then it throws an error.

> "Value for int_term_depth_eng must be between 0 and 6."

What is an expression that will allow up to 6 digits or +/- 5 digits?

Comment: [Range(minimum_value,maximum_value)] .. You specified maximum value 6. Thats why not allowing value greater than 6.

Comment: Well you only defined the range from 0-6, what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Range` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) dictates the numerical range that can be allowed as input. Thus it only allows between 0 and 6.

If you want it to allow 6 digits then you need to make it this

```
[Range(-99999, 999999, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
```

Comment: But it should also validate +/- 5 digits

Comment: What do you mean +/- 5?

Comment: What I mean to say that it should also allow 999999 or -99999

Comment: @Mahajan344 Do you mean that it must also accept negative numbers up to 5 digits?

Comment: @Mahajan344 Then set that to the lower limit. See my edit